# Why does my OnePlus One draw 60% more current if I turn off the screen AFTER plugging it in?

Tags: battery, charging, oneplus-one

It's pretty simple:

1. If I turn off the phone's screen and then connect the wall charger, the power supply draws ~6W from the wall, and this doesn't change if I keep waiting.
2. If I connect the wall charger and *then* turn off the phone's screen, the power supply draws ~10W, and I hear a very slightly audible high-pitched noise from the power supply the moment I turn off the screen.
   If I turn on the screen again, it goes back down to ~6W, but once it turns off it goes up again.

I have two questions:

1. What is causing this?
2. If it is intentional and not a bug, then what is the rationale for the cause? Is this well-known?

The ROM is CM11S 05Q.

(Yes, the charger & cable are the OEM's, and yes, I've actually measured the current.)

Comment: Yes 10 W is normal. In case 2, does the power supply in watts *not* reduce after turning the screen off . Please wait and observe.

Comment: @beeshyams: Well it's charged now, so it'll be a while before I can retry -- but I'm pretty sure when I charged it I didn't see it reduce until sometime after 90% (where I presume it had switched charging modes).

Comment: @beeshyams: I just tried it for 20 mins (~40% to ~70%); nothing went down on either end. The OPO Charging app reported 1800 mA average while the screen was off, and around 900 mA while it was on.

Comment: My bad. Interpreted it as screen being on in one case. As of now can't figure this. Will post if I can think through this

Comment: Can't think of any reason for this . Shot in the dark - try changing the power supply source. That noise makes it suspect but I can't see how that should affect on/ off power variation